# flattening the list of dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a List of dictionaries that have key and values and other info, like so:

```py
mylist  = [ {'key': 'captial' , 'value': 'captial of india'},
            {'key': 'captial' , 'value': 'captial of usa'},
            {'key': 'fruit' , 'value': 'colour of apple'},
            {'key': 'fruit' , 'value': 'colour of orange'}]
```

How do I flatten the list to get the below output

```py
result=[{'title':'captial',questions:[{text:'captial of usa'},{text:'captial of india'}]},
        {'title':'fruit',questions:[{text:'colour of apple'},{text:'colour of orange'}]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `defaultdict` and a list comprehension to achieve your results. `defaultdict` will group the values of the ***same keys*** present in `mylist` and then you put to use those grouped values with your custom keys(as required in your `result`) using a list comprehension.

```
from collections import defaultdict

mylist = [...]

a_list = defaultdict(list)

for item in mylist:
    a_list[item["key"]].append(item["value"])

result = [
    {"title": key, "questions": [{"text": v} for v in value]}
    for key, value in a_list.items()
]
```

**Output:**

```
[
    {
        "title": "captial",
        "questions": [{"text": "captial of india"}, {"text": "captial of usa"}],
    },
    {
        "title": "fruit",
        "questions": [{"text": "colour of apple"}, {"text": "colour of orange"}],
    },
]
```